# Primary Decomposition Theorem applied to projections in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

We have recently learned the Primary Decomposition Theorem in my Algebra course. I came up with what I think is an instance of this theorem but I haven't convinced myself.

Supposed we have the map $P: \mathbb{R}^2 -> \mathbb{R}^2$ where $P$ denotes a projection. Then suppose that the basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$ is $(u_1, u_2)$.

Now according the the primary decomposition theorem, I should be able to express $\mathbb{R}^2$ as an inner direct sum of the kernels... In my case the kernel of the projection to $u_1$ is exactly $u_2$ because they are orthogonal so multiples of $u_2$ will all map to zero when projected on $u_1$. The argument is symmetric for the kernel of $u_2$.

And in this case we actually can express $\mathbb{R}^2$ as a direct sum of $u_2$ and $u_1$.

I'm hoping somebody here can either help me expand on my idea or tell me where my logic is flawed.

Answer (score 0):

If $(u_1, u_2)$ is an orthogonal basis than the kernel of the projector to the subspace generated by $u_1$ is the span of $u_2$ i.e. all the vectors of the form $a u_1$ with $a \in\mathbb{R}$ ( if the vector space is over $\mathbb{R}$), not only $u_2$. The same is true for the projector to the subspace generated by $u_2$ and, yes, the whole space is the direct sum of the two subspaces.